# T-SQL Parse XML with identical nodes on same row

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need to parse following XML:
https://www.iftach.org/taxmatrix/charts/4Q2016.xml

Each of those RECORD nodes have to be in separate row:

```
<RECORD>
        <JURISDICTION ID="#15"  >AB</JURISDICTION>
        <COUNTRY>CAN</COUNTRY>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Gasoline</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Special Diesel</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Gasohol</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Propane</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.2700</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.0940</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>LNG</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>CNG</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Ethanol</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Methanol</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>E-85</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>M-85</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>A55</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Biodiesel</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
    </RECORD>
```

I want following columns in my set:

- Jurisdiction
- Country
- GasolineUSA
- GasolineCAN
- SpecialDieselUSA
- SpecialDieselCAN
- ...

Is this even possible in T_SQL? In C# I would just read XML top to bottom and connect TYPE to RATE based on position in XML. It's more convenient for me to have this in SQL though..

Comment: Can you assume there will only ever be 2 countries involved?  e.g. two RATE nodes after each FUEL_TYPE node?

Comment: @DanField Absolutely. This(CAN/USA) and number of FUEL_TYPE will be fixed unless laws change, but we don't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as far as getting the XML going, which to my mind is the harder part, yes you can:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<RECORD>
        <JURISDICTION ID="#15"  >AB</JURISDICTION>
        <COUNTRY>CAN</COUNTRY>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Gasoline</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Special Diesel</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Gasohol</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Propane</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.2700</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.0940</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>LNG</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>CNG</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.0000</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Ethanol</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Methanol</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>E-85</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>M-85</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>A55</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
        <FUEL_TYPE>Biodiesel</FUEL_TYPE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3734</RATE>
        <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
    </RECORD>'


;WITH xCTE AS
(
    SELECT @xml.query('
    <Data jurisdiction="{data(/RECORD/JURISDICTION/text())}" country="{data(/RECORD/COUNTRY/text())}">
        {
            for $x in (/RECORD/*[local-name() = "RATE"]) 
            return
                <FuelType name="{data(/RECORD/FUEL_TYPE[. << $x][last()])}" country="{data($x/@COUNTRY)}" value="{data($x)}" />
        }
    </Data>
        ') AS DocXml
)
SELECT
    x.n.value('../@jurisdiction', 'VARCHAR(10)') as Jurisdiction
    ,x.n.value('../@country', 'VARCHAR(5)') as Country
    ,x.n.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Name
    ,x.n.value('@country', 'VARCHAR(5)') as RateCountry
    ,x.n.value('@value', 'DECIMAL(10,4)') as Rate
FROM xCTE
CROSS APPLY DocXml.nodes('/Data/FuelType') x(n)
```

Basic idea: use XQuery in a CTE to transform the original document into something more manageable - getting the last `FUEL_TYPE` node that came before the current `RATE` node, and stuffing everything into a single XML element (or group of elements - attributes are a bit more compact and easier to work with here IMO).

This doesn't quite give you the output you want though - it gives an output like this:

```
Jurisdiction Country Name                 RateCountry Rate
------------ ------- -------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
AB           CAN     Gasoline             US          0.3734
AB           CAN     Gasoline             CAN         0.1300
AB           CAN     Special Diesel       US          0.3734
AB           CAN     Special Diesel       CAN         0.1300
...
```

If you want to go from there you should be able to do some kind of `CROSS APPLY` or `PIVOT`, but before I'd go down that road I'd consider if that's **really** what you want or if this will actually work better.

Comment: Dan, yes, it will give me enough to start

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, which might be a bit easier. The idea is roughly the same as in Dan's approach (which is great!).

The differenc: I use an `APPLY .nodes()` to get all the `<RATE>`nodes and look for **their last preceeding** `<FUEL_TYPE>`*.

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/RECORD/JURISDICTION/@ID)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS JURISDICTION_ID
      ,@xml.value(N'(/RECORD/JURISDICTION/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS JURISDICTION
      ,@xml.value(N'(/RECORD/COUNTRY/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS COUNTRY
      ,r.value(N'let $r:=. return ../FUEL_TYPE[.<<$r][last()]',N'varchar(max)') AS FUEL_TYPE
      ,r.value(N'(./@COUNTRY)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS RATE_COUNTRY
      ,r.value(N'(./@RATECHANGE)[1]',N'int') AS RATE_RATECHANGE
      ,r.value(N'(./text())[1]',N'decimal(8,4)') AS RATE

FROM @xml.nodes(N'/RECORD/RATE') AS A(r)
```

The first lines of the result:

```
+-----------------+--------------+---------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| JURISDICTION_ID | JURISDICTION | COUNTRY | FUEL_TYPE      | RATE_COUNTRY | RATE_RATECHANGE | RATE   |
+-----------------+--------------+---------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| #15             | AB           | CAN     | Gasoline       | US           | 0               | 0.3734 |
+-----------------+--------------+---------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| #15             | AB           | CAN     | Gasoline       | CAN          | 0               | 0.1300 |
+-----------------+--------------+---------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| #15             | AB           | CAN     | Special Diesel | US           | 0               | 0.3734 |
+-----------------+--------------+---------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| #15             | AB           | CAN     | Special Diesel | CAN          | 0               | 0.1300 |
+-----------------+--------------+---------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| #15             | AB           | CAN     | Gasohol        | US           | 0               | 0.3734 |
```

### UPDATE If hardcoded and in fixed order...

What about this *brute force* approach?

```
WITH Positions AS(SELECT * FROM (VALUES (3),(6),(9),(12),(15),(18),(21),(24),(27),(30),(33),(36)) AS v(Nr))
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/RECORD/*[sql:column("Positions.Nr")]/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS FUEL_TYPE
      ,@xml.value(N'(/RECORD/*[sql:column("Positions.Nr")+1]/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS RATE_US
      ,@xml.value(N'(/RECORD/*[sql:column("Positions.Nr")+2]/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS RATE_CAN

FROM Positions
```

Comment: Marked Dan's answer as solution, but in reality I did something like what you suggested. But I did pivot results to make it look like I wanted. I used `e.col.value('(RATE)[5]', 'Decimal(15,4)')` syntax to get to needed "RATE". They all in hardcoded order anyway

Comment: @katit If this is hardcoded order and never changes, you can go the easy way. See my udpate